# Aurelia custom element tests unable to load view

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, aurelia, custom-element

I'm facing problem while loading view in Aurelia test. Please refer below sample test code..

```js
import {StageComponent} from 'aurelia-testing';
import {bootstrap} from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = StageComponent
      .withResources('src/common/my-component')
      .inView('<my-component first-name.bind="firstName"></my-component>')
      .boundTo({ firstName: 'Bob' });
  });

  it('should render first name', done => {
    component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
      const nameElement = document.querySelector('.firstName');
      expect(nameElement.innerHTML).toBe('Bob');
      done();
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e.toString()) });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    component.dispose();
  });
});
```

I'm using karma for running tests with proxies as -

```
proxies: {
    '/base/jspm_packages/': '/base/wwwroot/jspm_packages/'
}
```

after running above test i'm able to load the view-model but it fails to load the view with following error -

> LOG: 'Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/src/common/my-component.html
>           Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/src/common/my-component.html
>           Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/src/common/my-component.html!http://localhost:9876/base/jspm_packages/github/systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.8.js
>           Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/src/common/my-component.html!template-registry-entry'

Thank you for you help in advance!

**UPDATE** --> Karma.conf.js file

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],

    jspm: {
      // Edit this to your needs
      loadFiles: ['test/unit/setup.js', 'test/unit/**/*.js'],
      serveFiles: ['src/**/*.js'],
      paths: {
        '*': 'src/*',
        'test/*': 'test/*',
        'github:*': 'jspm_packages/github/*',
        'npm:*': 'jspm_packages/npm/*'
      }
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [],
    proxies: {
        '/base/jspm_packages/': '/base/wwwroot/jspm_packages/'
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel', 'coverage']
    },
    'babelPreprocessor': {
      options: {
        sourceMap: 'inline',
        presets: ['es2015-loose', 'stage-1'],
        plugins: [
          'syntax-flow',
          'transform-decorators-legacy',
          'transform-flow-strip-types'
        ]
      }
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Comment: This is *probably* an issue with your karma config - can you share your `karma.conf.js` file?

Comment: @PWKad - Updated question with karma.conf.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that this line:

```
  serveFiles: ['src/**/*.js'],
```

should actually be this:

```
  serveFiles: ['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.html']
```

Normally your html would be bundled up with your component's js, but in this case you're serving the html directly.